# Compute and update the md5 hash after the fact

Tags: hash, md5, blob-storage

So... I just realized that the utility I’ve been using to upload data to azure blobs has only been setting content-md5 hashes for the small files, leaving the larger (more important) files without a hash.

What is the best way to compute and update the md5 hash for these blobs without downloading them?

Answer (score 0):

Per the [blob service API docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob), regarding Content-MD5:

> When omitted in version 2012-02-12 and later, the Blob service generates an MD5 hash.

So, if you trust that files were not tampered with while being transported to Azure, consider [get blob properties](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob-properties) and using its computed MD5.

For higher assurance requirements, integrity checking locally is better. As the whole point of this checksum is to confirm data round trips to Azure and back intact. Download a known good copy. Verify it, including computing MD5. Where available, you might cross check with more reliable checksums like SHA-2.